# Is this a valid review audit failure?

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits

Are answers that simply link to other answers acceptable?

The audit process says they are.  What are your thoughts on this?

[image: audit]

Comment: No, they are not. There is a Flag/Close as Duplicate option. Link only answers are also severely  frowned upon.

Comment: Why did I fail the review audit than?

Comment: Because audits are automated and can be wrong.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Because audits are chosen automatically, and sometimes they're bad

Comment: I feel like I need to be vindicated somehow

Comment: Vindicated how? It's one bad audit, there's no problem unless you fail multiple

Comment: I'm being cheeky

Comment: Done, answer is now deleted and should no longer qualify to be an audit https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27859462

Comment: @Larnu your comment should be posted as an answer - it will have more visibility.

Comment: I really dislike writing one liner answers like that, @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes . Also, it seemed in the end, the real question was "Why did I fail this audit", not "are link only answer to other questions ok?"

Comment: Go ahead and feel vindicated: the audit was a bum one. That's definitely not a valid answer (because it consists of nothing more than a link to another answer), and it should have been flagged as "not an answer". We're sorry about bum audits. They happen sometimes, because they are automatically chosen by the system, and the system sometimes gets it wrong. This has been handled in this case. In the future, you can go ahead and open the post in a new tab and flag it as you normally would, even after failing an audit. This allows us to handle the problem, which will remove it as an audit, too.

Comment: @Larnu you're correct.  I changed the wording.  Ironically the question was closed as a duplicate.  This is super meta.... on meta.stackoverflow.... another irony lol

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Are answers that simply link to other answers acceptable?

No. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

> In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid link-rot), we prefer answer that provide at least a summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information.

Comment: "link-rot" isn't really a problem for site-internal links, but the "immediately helpful" part still stands. I'd think the problem is more that the question would be a duplicate if the answer was identical so it should be closed on that grounds. But if there really was a question that wasn't a duplicate but could be answered by another answer, duplicating the answer seems dubious (if one answer gets corrected/improved the other doesn't profit)

Comment: @Voo - I have seen valid answers after 6 months get deleted for a variety of reasons.  I don't care if it's an external website or an Stack Exchange community website.  The reference material should be quoted and cited, allowing the answer to exist within the answer itself, otherwise just submit a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad audit - it should be flagged as Not An Answer.

If an answer on a different question fully answers the question, the question should be flagged as a duplicate of the question that has the answer. If it does *not* fully answer the question, then a link to the answer won't fully answer the question either. (In this case, the answer should, at a minimum, explain how to adapt the other answer to the unique circumstances of the question at hand).

Answer (score -14):

It may depend on the context. **Off site** link only answers are severely frowned upon. They should be flagged and deleted.

If the question is really a duplicate, that means if the answers to the other question answer this one, then again an *internal* link only answer should be flagged and deleted because the correct action should be to close the question as a duplicate.

But there are real world questions, where a link to a different answer can have value, even if the question is not a duplicate. IMHO, the term workaround has to be considered. If the answer in the link do not really solve the question, but can be used as a short term workaround, then there is no solution a part from a link to that other post. Of course it would be better to have a little explaination in the answer itself and not a raw link. But deleting the answer could be worse for future readers than leaving it.

Disclaimer: I have not read the real question and answer so I cannot know whether this apply to the specific question.

Disclaimer2: The point is not whether a link only answer is a good answer (obviously it cannot), but just whether deleting it will make the site better.

Comment: In other words, link-only answers are not OK in any form ;-)

Comment: @P.P My point is just that deleting them can be worse that leaving them in some use cases. But I know that it is no more than my opinion...

Comment: I agree that the just because to questions have the same answer it doesn't necessarily mean it's a duplicate.  I would have taken the answer from the linked question, rewrote it as an answer to the new question, and provided a citation at the bottom.  This way it's not a "link only" answer, but its not really plagaizing/dishonest

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli The duplicate message says "This question **already has answers** here..."  Doesn't that imply that the requirement for being a duplicate isn't that the *question* is the same, it's that the *answer* is the same? (I agree that the duplicates should be sufficiently similar that it should be clear how to apply the answer to the new question, though).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I would have to think about the implication of that wording.  Thinking of it from a mathematical perspective, lets say the original question is "what is 2+2+2", would we then flag another question that says "what is 3*2".  It seems in this case the the question's with the answer are so different that it would not warrant flagging.  Im unsure about what the implication of the current wording is, but if the logical implication is that all questions with the same answer are duplicates then I vote we change the wording.  Great point

Comment: If the answer to both questions is exactly the same, then it's a duplicate and should be closed as such. If it isn't, then even if the answers are *similar* they still need to be tailored specifically to each question. There is no situation where posting a link to another answer and nothing else is the correct action.